# Wrapping blocks based API in convenience methods

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to access a web api (although this would apply to NSURLSession as well), and currently I have a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
[self.rottenTomatoesManager GET:@"movies.json" parameters:@{@"q" : searchString, @"apikey" : [self.rottenTomatoesManager apiKey]}
                                success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
                                    if(response.statusCode == 200){
                                        NSDictionary *responseData = responseObject;
                                        self.searchResults = responseData[@"movies"];
                                        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
                                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                                    }
        }
                                failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Error loading movies %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
```

I'd like to take that functionality and wrap it in a convenience method that looks something like this

```
NSArray *results = [self.rottenTomatoesManager searchMoviesWithTitle:@"The avengers"]
```

to clean up the ViewController code and to make most of the code framework agnostic.

What is the best way to do this so that I'm not turning a nice asynchronous blocks based API into a synchronous API?

Comment: you don't want to change asyn API to sync API. because blocking is bad (block is good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback blocks are great for this.

```
[self loadSomethingWithCallback:^(NSArray *results) {
    NSLog(@"%@", results);
}];
```

Comment: I assume you then execute the block inside of the AFNetworking success block?

Comment: Correct, and you'll probably want to also run it in the failure block with an empty array or perhaps nil.

Comment: Now I'm thinking that it should just be a block with no return type. Update the tableview in that block and call that block from the AFNetworking blocks.

Comment: Your typical callback block takes an object(id) and returns void.