# Passing a variable out of block in completionHandler - __block is not helping me out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization, objective-c-blocks

I think i need to modify this method to return the variable provided by the completionHandler - Any body know how do i do it the correct way?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self getLanguageOfText:content]);
});



- (NSString *)getLanguageOfText:(NSString *)fewSentences {
__block NSString *returnLanguageString = @"Navi";

NSSpellChecker *spellChecker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];
[spellChecker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:YES];
NSString *spellCheckText = fewSentences;

[spellChecker requestCheckingOfString:spellCheckText
                                range:(NSRange) {0, [spellCheckText length] }
                                types:NSTextCheckingTypeOrthography
                              options:nil
               inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
                    completionHandler: ^(NSInteger sequenceNumber, NSArray *results, NSOrthography *orthography, NSInteger wordCount) {
    //NSLog(@"dominant language = %@", orthography.dominantLanguage);
    //language = @"Hi";

    NSLog(@"dominant language = %@", orthography.dominantLanguage);

    returnLanguageString = orthography.dominantLanguage;
}];

return returnLanguageString;
}
```

But the returnLanguageString is always "Navi" but i want the orthography.dominantLanguage to be returned.

Please note : I need to have this method and the NSSpellChecker code

The few sentences i mentioned above will be like this and it is stored in NSString :

```
40
00:02:59.000 --> 00:03:01.000
彼らは私達にメッセージを送った

41
00:03:01.000 --> 00:03:03.000
彼らは彼らが望むものは何でも取ることができる

42
00:03:04.000 --> 00:03:05.000
我々は彼らにメッセージを送信します。

43
00:03:07.000 --> 00:03:09.000
これは私たちの土地である
```

Comment: Are you trying to print  NSLog(@"dominant language = %@", orthography.dominantLanguage); or printing from spellchecker?  Your spell checker completion handler has return type of NSString?

Comment: Yes return type is __NSCFConstantString

Comment: You are going about this all wrong. Don't try to return a value when the result is acquired asynchronously. You should be using callback blocks. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253207/wrapping-blocks-based-api-in-convenience-methods/24253250#24253250

Comment: HI CRIMSON THANKS. I updated the code above - i refered your link also. But i am not getting it - i donlt know where this code

[self loadSomethingWithCallback:^(NSArray *results) {
    NSLog(@"%@", results);
}];

extactly fits above!

Comment: Here's an example of callback blocks in action. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154141/ios-best-way-to-do-this-w-o-calling-method-32-times/24154482#24154482

Answer (score 1):

your block is running asynchronously.  That means that it doesn't complete execution before your function returns--and the return value is unchanged.

You will need to handle setting this variable asynchronously.  The easiest thing to do is use a block, eg:

```
- (void)getLanguageOfText:(NSString *)fewSentences {

    NSSpellChecker *spellChecker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];
    [spellChecker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:YES];
    NSString *spellCheckText = fewSentences;

    [spellChecker requestCheckingOfString:spellCheckText
                                    range:(NSRange) {0, [spellCheckText length] }
                                    types:NSTextCheckingTypeOrthography
                                  options:nil
                   inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
                        completionHandler: ^(NSInteger sequenceNumber, NSArray *results, NSOrthography *orthography, NSInteger wordCount) {

        NSString * returnLanguageString = orthography.dominantLanguage;

        // handle the result somehow on the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ^{
            [self doSomethingWithResult:returnLanguageString];
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: No Success ... Here is my code

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", [self getLanguageOfText:content]);
    });

Comment: You _can't_ and _shouldn't_ return the result using the return value of your method. Your method should return void. This answer is trying to tell you to call a "response received" method when you get your response. I prefer callback blocks myself. See my comment above.

Comment: You're doing it wrong user226372.  Please re-read my answer.  You are calling an asynchronous method from within your getLanguageOfText method.  The completion handler block for requestCheckingOfString doesn't get invoked until *after* getLanguageOfText has already returned.  In my answer I didn't suggest that you call getLanguageOfText from within another block.  I suggested that you put that code inside your completion handler for requestCheckingOfString--and then invoke some code that does something with the result.  I will update my answer to make it a little more obvious.